# Ruby gem for ical feed like in Airbnb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, icalendar

I am making a booking engine website. The booking on same apartment can come from different agents too. So, I want to be able to sync calendar on every 30 minutes(or similar). Also, I want to be able to import Ical feed or export it just like how Airbnb does it. I am creating the site on Ruby on Rails. So, is there any good gem out there that I could use? If not, how do I make it from scratch? Any tips or links or tutorials??

Comment: For the scheduling tasks (that will run every 30 minutes), you can use the [Whenever gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever).

Answer (score 1):

I think the `fullcalendar` (https://fullcalendar.io/) JavaScript library would be perfect for your use case. There's a Rails wrapper which makes it super easy to integrate into Rails: https://github.com/bokmann/fullcalendar-rails.

You can pull events from a Google Calendar by just providing it `googleCalendarId` documented here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/google_calendar/.

In order to actually export/add events to your Google Calendar, you'll have to post to Google's APIs. You can use this library: https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client.